# recognize applicationDidBecomeActive from a specific UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift3

I was wondering if there is a way or method to use to operate a piece of code when and app is called from the background and becomes active. I need the method to work from the view itself and not the app delegate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you  have to used the  listener of **UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification** when you need to do  some action in your view controller on wake up from background

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.executeMethod), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
}

func executeMethod()  {
    // execute your code here
}
```